# Add PIN contact to BBM Programmatically

Tags: java, blackberry

Is it possible to add a blackberry PIN to a device's 'black berry messenger' contact list programmatically?

Can anyone verify this for me?

I have looked through the API, but I do not see a clear way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Before you begin:** Make sure that you have completed the task, [Register your application with the BlackBerry Messenger platform](http://docs.blackberry.com/id-id/developers/deliverables/25690/Register_your_app_with_the_BBM_Platform_1387557_11.jsp), and that the class that displays the MyBBMChatScreen screen passes in a reference to the application's associated BBMPlatformContext object into the screen's contructor. (as always :D)

I use this codes to add just one contact. You can modify it to add multiple contact. Just change the size of ***contacts*** array.

```
String PIN = "123456";
String name = "Someone";
BBMInvitationRequest[] contacts = new BBMInvitationRequest[1];

contacts[0] = new BBMInvitationRequest(PIN, name);
platformContext.getUIService().inviteToBBM(contacts);
```

May this help :)

Comment: hi,is there any jar files to add with BBM,am getting error's in the following lines BBMPlatformApplication,BBMPlatformContextListener,      BBMPlatformContext,BBMPlatformManager where can i download this classes